# Phalcon не высылает cookie

Tags: php, nginx, cookie, phalcon

Пробую задать куки, как через setcookie, так и через $this->cookies->set/send, но почему то сервер не передает заголовки с куками, причем что самое интересное, при входе на "/admin" все хорошо работает, а на других - нет, никаких ошибок не выводиться, куки пробую задать перед всем контентом, не подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

P.S. проект не мой, как мне разказали, раньше все работало нормально, но после каких то обновлений на сервере, перестало.

Версия phalcon 3.3.1
Сервер nginx
Версия php 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все просто, на сервере был установлен Varnish, и его настройки выглядели так:

```
if (!(bereq.url ~ "^/admin")) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    unset beresp.http.cookie;
    unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    unset beresp.http.Pragma;
    unset beresp.http.Server;
}
```

Теперь все стало на свои места :)